# Is it possible to have an HMap from a type A to multiple other types?

Tags: scala, shapeless

[Shapeless has `HMap`s](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0) for enforcing type safety of heterogenous maps, but it doesn't seem to allow mapping from a certain type to multiple types.

In other words, this is valid:

```scala
class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val stringToInt = new BiMapIS[String, Int]
implicit val intToString = new BiMapIS[Int, String]

val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](23 -> "foo", "bar" -> 13)
```

But this is not:

```scala
class BiMapIS[K, V]
implicit val stringToInt    = new BiMapIS[String, Int]
implicit val stringToString = new BiMapIS[String, String]

val hm = HMap[BiMapIS]("val1" -> 1, "val2" -> "two")
```

**My question is:** Is there a way to allow type safe mappings from one type (e.g., `String`) to multiple types (e.g., both `String` and `Int`)?

Also, I'm not married to Shapeless for this solution.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this requires some plumbing: use `Coproduct` to list out all the possible values:

```
class BiMapIS[K, V] { type Value = V }
implicit object strKey extends BiMapIS[String, Coproduct.`Int, String`.T]
implicit object intKey extends BiMapIS[Int,    Coproduct.`Boolean`.T]

val hm = HMap[BiMapIS](
  "val1" -> Coproduct[strKey.Value](1),
  "val2" -> Coproduct[strKey.Value]("two"),
  3      -> Coproduct[intKey.Value](true)
)
```

Then, you can make yourself a helpful ops class to faciliate getting values out of the `HMap`:

```
implicit class HMapOps[R[_,_]](hm: HMap[R]) {
  def atKey[K,C <: Coproduct](k: K)(implicit ev1: R[K, C]) = new {
    def withValueType[V](implicit ev2: shapeless.ops.coproduct.Selector[C, V]): Option[V] = 
      hm.get(k).flatMap(_.select[V])
  }
}
```

Putting it all together:

```
scala> hm.atKey("val1").withValueType[Int]
res1: Option[Int] = Some(1)

scala> hm.atKey("val1").withValueType[String]
res2: Option[String] = None

scala> hm.atKey("val1").withValueType[Boolean]   // String never maps to Boolean!!!
<console>: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev2: shapeless.ops.coproduct.Selector[shapeless.:+:[Int,shapeless.:+:[String,shapeless.CNil]],Boolean]
       hm.atKey("val1").withValueType[Boolean]
```